# Rustup says protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: curl, https, rustup

I have been trying to use Rustup for a while now and it says this when I try to do anything with it:

```
info: caused by: [1] Unsupported protocol (Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl)
```

I know that cURL has HTTPS enabled — I just tried using it and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I assume it is because rustup isn't calling curl directly, but statically compiled library on their build platform :(

Yeah, looking at my rustup binary I see all the static symbols in it for curl. Are you also trying to install from an ARM-based machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ARM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not what you want to hear, but they have [known issues at the moment with ARM](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs/issues/1051).

This workaround seems to work for me:

- Directly download rustup-init from https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs for your platform
- `env RUSTUP_USE_HYPER=1 ./rustup-init`

It should also work to `export RUSTUP_USE_HYPER=1` (assuming you aren't using tcsh) before running the rustup script, but the above is what I tested and used.

Comment: I just built my first rust executable! So the above changes did work out well for me.